# Aligning + and - for shopping basket incrementer

Tags: html, css

I want to have my code like in this image
[image]

It is a simple shopping basket incrementer. I put the border around for 1 but i'm not sure how to align + and - and put the border around. I searched for many incrementers but I couldn't find one like in the image.

Someone please give me a help.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

  $(".button").on("click", function() {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
     var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
   } else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
     } else {
        newVal = 0;
      }
   }

    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

  });

});
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  font: bold 20px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 3px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="numbers-row">
    <input type="text"  id="incrementer" value="1">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try below code:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

  $(".button").on("click", function() {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
     var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
   } else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
     } else {
        newVal = 0;
      }
   }

    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

  });

});
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  float: left;
  font: bold 20px Helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 11px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50px;
}
.inc.button {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  left: 57px;
  padding: 0 6px 0 8px;
  position: absolute;
}
.dec.button {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  left: 57px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="numbers-row">
    <input type="text"  id="incrementer" value="1">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget JavaScript. Just use a number input in the first place.

```css
input[type=number] {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  font: bold 20px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 3px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="numbers-row">
    <input type="number"  id="incrementer" min="0" value="1">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the post is not about the js but about the aligning + and -, because I have to have them like in the image. Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just add some icons in place of + and minus sign and there you go.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

  $(".button").on("click", function() {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
     var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
   } else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
     } else {
        newVal = 0;
      }
   }

    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

  });

});
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  font: bold 20px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 3px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #C9C6C6;
}

.inc.button {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #C9C6C6;
 left: 41px;
 height: 13px;
 top: 2px;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.dec.button {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #C9C6C6;
 left: 30px;
 height: 7px;
 top: 16px;
 width: 9px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
 padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="numbers-row">
    <input type="text"  id="incrementer" value="1">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```